Am I removing this carpet runner correctly, to lay traction pads or other refinishing options?
There's a basement staircase I've mentioned in other posts, which has some issues but is sturdy and usable. One issue is its carpet runner is disintegrating, dispersing black foam and plastic fiber dust under and around it over time. I am removing the carpet runner, cleaning it up, then will apply some sort of tread on each stair. (That's a seperate question but I'm envisioning each step getting a patch of carpet, or anti-skid mat, or something like that which can ideally be cleanly removed later if a redesign is decided on.)
So far so good, I'm about a quarter way through initial removal and will need to do a final sanding or something to clean the stairs and risers. I want to check, am I going about this correctly? By correct I mean, most efficiently, safely, and using the right techniques, to be able to apply the kind of finishing (just traction pads) I envision.
What I'm doing is using a cutter to seperate sections of carpet on the riser and step, then using a pry bar to yank the carpet up. I pull off what I can, then start scraping the foam underneath using various types of paint scrapers. I use plyers or hammer to yank or flatten any tacks leftover on the risers.
It seems like at the end I will need to sand or just do more scraping to get a clean wood underneath. Or is there a reasonable solvent I can use to remove the foam and glue like isopropyl alcohol? I imagine that'll damage the word worse than elbow grease scraping. If what I'm doing now is functionally sufficient to get a smooth surface and further cleaning any last sign of foam would just be aesthetic, I don't need to make it perfect. The wood on either side of the riser is a different color already, and I plan to lay traction pads over most of the steps where the runner carpet was, so even getting every bit of foam/glue off will not make a perfectly clean look. I just want the next step of traction pads or future carpet possibilities to be ready. This is a basement staircase, I'm most concerned about function and safety.
PPE I'm confident about - goggles, mask, gloves, shop vac and broom to clean, ventilation and tarps for workspace.
Here's photos of the process and tools I'm using. Confirmation or corrections about this would be appreciated, thanks.








If using a mask, you should be good.  Covering it over, then just getting it flat should be good enough.   The stairs look good enough for staining if going that far, but traction seems to be main idea, so sanding should not be needed/wanted, just flat enough to recover.  The risers might be a problem depending on what you want done to them.  They need less flattening if covered, but more work if staining.

Questions of staining or sanding or covering are just aesthetic, other than traction provided by whatever final surface of treads are (raw vs stained vs painted vs covered wood), right? @crip659 again I'm mainly concerned about function/safety, future adaptability, and after that eco-friendly construction (which limits some finishing options)
